# Android Fragment's onClickListener not called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

I have a fragement that has a header with two buttons and a list on it. I want to get events on those items. The fragment is dynamically added to the UI, and my app is for android 16 and upwards, so I don't have to use the support lib. 
I decided to implement the click listeners to the both the buttons and the list on the MainActivity since these fire off database look ups, and I would like to keep my db lookups in one place. so, I made a main activity that implements both: OnClickListener and OnItemClickListener and added the following methods:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Click"+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

To call the fragment I do:

```
//get a list of the data
Fragment sideFormations=sideFragment.newInstance(list);
sideFormations.setClickListeners(this,this); //<--important bit
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "listeners set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.side_frame,sideFormations);
ft.commit();
```

In the frag's setClickListener's method, I set save the values passed in as click listeners.and the relevant sections of the frag are:

```
onCreateView: //nflate the views, setAdapter for the list, ensure clickability of the views
onStart: //assign click listeners which were passed in to the list, and to the header.
```

I still can't catch clicks in the main activity ie. zero but no errors. Any ideas will be highly welcome, and appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Adding code where I define the listeners for the views.

```
//This is the latest iteration. As I mentioned, I have tried to set these at different places in the frag's lifecycle without much success:
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            Log.d("CLICK-VIEW","List Clicked");
            main.onItemClick(arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3);
        }               
    });
    mHeaderView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            Log.d("CLICK-VIEW","Header Clicked");
            //main.onClick(v);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: could you please add your code where you define the Listener to the views?

Comment: @owe Hey. Thanks. I will add it now.

Comment: Thats strange...but: you say your headerView consists of two Buttons. You should add a ClickListener to each button, now it seemas that you're adding the listener to the layout where the buttons inside. Plz post your complete activity and the xml files. It isn't really hard to set listeners to views (see answer of Biraj Zalavadia), so iI think there's perhaps another problem in your code.

Answer (score 1):

*You can not put listeners for fragment directly to MainActivity.class because the view that created are owned by fragment and fragment is owned by activity dynamically right? So the same case was with me and I resolve like this :*

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    //Create two public methods

   public void onFragmentListClick(params whtever you want to pass){
     //will call from fragment when list item click
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   public void onFragmentButtomClick(params whtever you want to pass){
     //will call from fragment when button click
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

**Fragment.class**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
  private Button b;
  private ListView lst;

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(setLayoutId(), container, false);
b = (Button)fragmentView.findViewById()     
lst = (ListView)fragmentView.findViewById()     

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onFragmentButtomClick(..);
            }
        });

        lst.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onFragmentListClick(..);         
            }
        });

        return fragmentView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Biraj. I tried your solution, and it doesn't seem to work. but in trying it, I have discovered that my problem is deeper than that. Even a regular click listener-one that is defined exactly after getting the View-- won't work. Is there stuff I should look into??? The damn listener just doesn't register clicks.